# not able to filter data_extension_column output in python

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, fuel-sdk, python

```
import FuelSDK
arg = {'clientid':'clientid', 'clientsecret':'clientsecret'}
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(False, False, params=arg)
data_extension_column = FuelSDK.ET_DataExtension_Column()
data_extension_column.auth_stub = myClient
data_extension_column.props = ["Name", "FieldType"]

# data_extension_column.search_filter = {'Property': 'CustomerKey', 'SimpleOperator': 'equals',
#                                        'Value': 'Value' }

data_extension_column.search_filter = {'Property': 'Name', 'SimpleOperator': 'equals',
                                       'Value': 'Data Extension Name'}
all_columns = data_extension_column.get()
```

When fetching the details without filter I'm able to retrieve the details whereas when using filter I'm not getting any result.
I have rechecked I'm passing the customer key or name as application from the `data_extension.get()` output

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce? I would suggest to post this question on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I would say it's pretty obviously about Salesforce. FuelSDK and Data Extensions are both clear indicators.